# Change value of a variable x in main method through running thread

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    int maxScore = 0;

Thread student = new Thread(client,????);
student.start();
}
```

I want student thread to change value of maxScore, how do I do it in Java? (Like in C we can pass the address of maxScore)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. There is no way you can change the value of a local variable from another thread.

You can, however, use a mutable type that has an `int` field, and pass it to the new thread. For example:

```
public class MutableInt {
    private int value;
    public void setValue(..) {..}
    public int getValue() {..};
}
```

(Apache commons-lang provide a `MutableInt` class which you can reuse)

Update: for a global variable you can simple use `public static` fields. Note that if you are willing not only to store some values in them, but also read them and do stuff depending on that, you would need to use `synchronized` blocks, or `AtomicInteger`, depending on the usages.

Comment: I actually want a global variable that all the threads can access to read the value, change the value. Is there any way?

Comment: Just a quick update, even though I know this is an old answer. If you're using [Apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), you can also use the `MutableObject<T>`, rather than defining a separate object for each Mutable type you want: [MutableObject<T>](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/mutable/MutableObject.html)

Answer (score 9):

You need a class object, if you want to modify value in separate thread. For example:

```
public class Main {

    private static class Score {
        public int maxScore;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        final Score score = new Score();
        score.maxScore = 1;

        System.out.println("Initial maxScore: " + score.maxScore);

        Thread student = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                score.maxScore++;
            }
        };

        student.start();
        student.join(); // waiting for thread to finish

        System.out.println("Result maxScore: " + score.maxScore);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use array (of one element):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        final int[] score = new int[1];
        score[0] = 1;

        System.out.println("Initial maxScore: " + score[0]);

        Thread student = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                score[0]++;
            }
        };

        student.start();
        student.join(); // waiting for thread to finish

        System.out.println("Result maxScore: " + score[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding Synchronized to the methods was a solution for me, thanks